# SSL certificate expired the same day of creation

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I've created an SSL certificate for WAMP. The certificate is well-created, but in the browser it shows me that the certificate has expired!

This is what I've done :

```
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha1 -key private.key
-out certificat.crt -days 36500
-config C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.21\conf\openssl.cnf
```

I've specified 36500 days, but it shows me in the certificate information:

```
valid From : 15/09/2013   to : 16/07/1977
```

I created it yesterday; I don't know where problem is.

Comment: You shouldn't specify crazy periods like 100 years. Even if it worked, which it didn't, it would defeat the purpose entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the maximum is probably lower. [According to this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mailing.openssl.users/3kK_f0ywCZQ) (a little old, but perhaps still relevant), the days get converted to seconds (60 * 60 * 24 * 36500 = 3153600000 seconds), but the value's stored in a `long` (with a maximum value of 2147483647), so it overflows and gives you the bunk date.

The post above (verified with a little math) suggests the maximum would be around 24854 days.

Answer (score 4):

Days property in openssl is limited to max positive value `11499`.

Values bigger go negative and Certificate Verification is therefore considered "Expired".